# SQL Server Compact unable to insert

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-ce

I am trying to run this simple query. The query does not fail with an error and instead appears to execute successfully. However, upon refreshing the DB the insert has not occurred. 
It connects fine and returns that it has affected one row.

Where is the below going wrong?

```
using(SqlCeConnection Con = new SqlCeConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.dbConnectionString))
{ 
    Con.Open(); 
    SqlCeCommand Query = new SqlCeCommand("INSERT INTO DataTable2(num) VALUES(5)",Con); 

    try
    {
        Query.ExecuteNonQuery();
        MessageBox.Show(Query.ExecuteNonQuery().ToString());
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try associating that command to a transaction and then committing that transaction. I believe I had to do that when I worked with SqlCe but it's been a while so I'm not sure.

Comment: you are running the INSERT statement twice, you know this right?  what does your conn string look like?

Comment: What is the connection string? And what do you mean with _refreshing the DB_?

Comment: Yes I soon realised it was running twice (i) the planned time to run it (ii) when I made it report to a message box. 
By refreshing I mean re-running SELECT * on the table within the Database Explorer of Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: Connection string is - Data Source=|DataDirectory|\db.sdf . I know it works, if I change the table name to a table that does not exist it reports an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use the substitution string `DataDirectory` you should remember that it resolves to a different location. APP_DATA for WEB Apps, `BIN\DEBUG` for WinForms application.

The database updated is the one in that directory, probably you are looking at the wrong database. Check if the connection used in Server Explorer or in the Sql Server Compact Toolbox points to the actual database updated and not to the one present in the project folder.

Comment: Perfect, and that does seems rather obvious now. Refreshing the DB within VS is refreshing a database that is not modified by the query executed when testing the program.

Comment: And if you have your db listed between the project files check also the Copy To Output Directory property to avoid overwriting your working db with the empty one in the project folder